# WCF duplex requests time delay

Tags: wcf

I have an simple Pub/Sub service built on WCF. the interface of server side looks like below:

```
[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class RDFService : IRDFService
{
 public Guid Register(string ric)
 public void Unregister(Guid guid)
}
```

Client side call back interface:

```
  [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
internal class ServiceCallback : IRDFCallBack
{
 // [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
 public void UpdateSignal(Guid guid, string ric, MarketFeedData data, MarketDataMessageType type)
}
```

Client side is an Win form project.

The handling logic is as below:
   If client receives an UpdateSignal request, withing the handling method, client will make an call to unregister it self.

Usually, both UpdateSignal and Unreg methods takes almost no time. But when an influx(8-10) of UpdateSignal requests are sent to client concurrently, there's a significant delay between 1-3 seconds. I opened trace and found that the time are held on the Unregister service method call:
[image]

As in the picture, there's an 2 seconds delay between activity 3 and 4. What can be the cause? Thanks.

Comment: How do you host your services? Can it be affected by throttling?

Comment: Do you handle any state of the clients on your server implementation that requires you to use "Lock" statements to guarantee thread-safe operations?
Depending on how you use it Lock can delay your entire publishing pipeline.